# CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (60)

Tags: python, flask, curl, pem

I have created a api in flask/python.When someone call my api then it gives error

```
CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (60)
The remote server's SSL certificate or SSH md5 fingerprint was deemed not OK. This error code has been unified with CURLE_SSL_CACERT since 7.62.0. Its previous value was 51
```

When i gone through this error then i found i need add a `pem file` for Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1. I downloaded pem file from below url.

`https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm`

But i didn't know how to add it.I am not sure i am going on right way.Can someone me guide what i should to need for resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You must update python version.

Comment: This does not answer the question